# Validate Date Based on 'MM-DD-YYYY-HH-mm-ss'

Tags: powershell

I'd like to force a user to use a specific date string for use in my functions.  is there a means to do this with ValidatePattern in Powershell.  I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work:

```
function Test-Date {
  Param(
    [ValidatePattern('MM-DD-YYYY-HH-mm-ss')]
    [DateTime]$date
  )
  Write-Output $date
}
```

Comment: You don't need `ValidatePattern` because you are already dictating that the parameter is a `DateTime` object.

Comment: Or, if you're actually getting a string, change the data type to `[string]` and validate against the pattern `^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}$`. `ValidatePattern()` expects a regular expression, not a format string.

Comment: Bill you are correct I re-formulated my question in to I think is the right answer based on your feedback... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I found the answer to my own question.  I wanted to verify that I got a date from the user in a specific fashion so I could tell them how to enter the date as I expect it to be.  I wanted the date format in general short date and short time so I used 'g' as my pattern.  Additional patterns I found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
   function Test-Date
  {param(
    [ValidateScript(
    {
        try{[datetime]::ParseExact($psitem ,'g' ,[System.Globalization.CultureInfo](Get-Culture))}catch{throw "Datetime is in the wrong format ($_) Use this format 8/30/2007 11:20 AM"}
    })]
    [string]$date


  )
   Write-Output $date
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For enforcing a particular format for parameter values I wouldn't recommend parsing the value in a `ValidateScript()` block and throwing an exception on a mismatch. Validate the string via `ValidatePattern()` and parse only valid parameters in the function body.

```
function Test-Date {
    Param(
        [ValidatePattern('^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} [AP]M$')]
        [string]$date
    )

    $culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
    [DateTime]::ParseExact($date, 'g', $culture)
}
```

With that said, I'd expect a function `Test-Date` to return a boolean value indicating whether or not the string was a valid date, so I probably wouldn't do the validation in the `Param()` block in the first place. I'd prefer something like this:

```
function Test-Date {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Date
    )

    $Date -match '^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} [AP]M$'
}
```

or like this, if you want to be culture-agnostic:

```
function Test-Date {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Date
    )

    $culture = Get-Culture
    try {
        [void][DateTime]::ParseExact($Date, 'g', $culture)
        $true
    } catch {
        $false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback much appreciated